# How to setup Heroku toolbelt on c9

Tags: heroku, terminal, installation, c9.io

I'm having trouble with the directions from c9 documentation on setting up the Heroku Toolbelt on c9:

https://docs.c9.io/docs/deploying-via-cli

**This is what I'm entering in the terminal:**

$ awscli-bundle.zip\n$ apt-get awscli-bundle.zip\n$ manually update; heroku-toolbelt sh

**However, it is returning an error:**

bash: awscli-bundle.zipn$: command not found

bash: heroku-toolbelt: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That section of the documentation looks badly mangled to me. `awscli-bundle.zip` is used for Amazon Web Services, not Heroku.

[An older version of that page](https://web.archive.org/web/20161205042408/https://docs.c9.io/docs/deploying-via-cli) shows this command instead:

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

This looks a lot more reasonable.

I just tried this out on a new c9 VM and my `heroku` binary was successfully upgraded from version 3.43.13 to 3.43.16.